# display data from database in append input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code that appends the input tag when i cliked the button

```
var max_fields = 10;
var wrapper = $("#container"); 
var add_button = $(".add_form_field"); 

var x = 1; 
$(add_button).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ 
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group label-floating"><label class="label">title</label><input type="text" id="title_name'+x+'" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
    } else {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
});
```

I used ajax call to get the data from my database

```
 $.ajax({
      url:'../ajax/gettitle.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{userid:user},
      dataType:'JSON',
      success: function(result){
         $('#title_name'+x).val(result.title_name);
      console.log(result);
      },
      error:function(status){

      }
  });
```

and this is my **gettitle.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
    $id = $_POST['userid'];
    $data = $user->getTitle($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function getTitle($titleid) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_title WHERE title_userid = '$titleid'";
    $view = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $view->execute();
    $userdata = $view->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $userdata;
}
```

and this is the query I use..

Now my problem is how can i display the returned data from my append input field, because whenever I tried it doesn't display anything.
This is the returned data from my ajax call[image]
What I wanted is to display both `title_name` on my input field. Like if I have two array of data supposedly two input field will show up with the data from my database and like if there is a data on my input field what I want to achieve is  the input field will show up.

Comment: `"whenever i tried it doesn't display anything"` - What did you try?  The code in the question doesn't contain this.  In general you would perform this action in the `success` callback of your AJAX function.

Comment: Need that code to answer your question.
Another thing, No need to do '`$(add_button).click()`' '`add_button.click()`' is enough

Comment: but what's the difference between the two?.. is it not appropriate to use `$(add_button).click()`??

Comment: @LionSmith - that is doing double jQuery...if your variable is already a jQuery object then why would you possibly wrap is with a `$` again?!? makes null sense. Also, your code is horrible.. please make order! it's a complete mess.

Comment: isee thanks for the information.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to modify your gettitle.php file instead of returning objects it need to return html code, which you can bind with your html file. As I understand from your question, here what you need to modify
**gettitle.php**

```
<?php foreach(exam-array as value){ ?>
  <div class="form-group label-floating"><label class="label">title</label><input type="text" id="<?php echo value['title_name']; ?>" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now on sucees call art you modify this one

```
success: function(result){
      $(wrapper).append(result);
  }
```

Let me know if you need any further assistance